# Dropdown submenu stays open

Tags: jquery, angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Dropdown submenu stays open even after I click on same level "li" item. How to close the dropdown submenu when i click on other items i.e "View Draft/Past Application" and "log out"?
This is my code.

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right  nav-item">
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="goHome()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> <strong>Home</strong></a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown" data-ng-controller="rootController" uib-dropdown>
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                    <strong>Welcome {{authentication.userName}}</strong>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu >
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>   Manage Account</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu style="top:100%;right:100%">
                                            <li role="menuitem" ><a data-ui-sref="ManageProfile" data-ng-click='go()'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>   View/Edit Organisation Profile</a></li>
                                            <li role="menuitem" ><a data-ui-sref="ManagePersonalProfile" data-ng-click='go()'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>   View/Edit Personal Profile</a></li>
                                            <li role="menuitem"><a data-ui-sref="AddBranch" data-ng-click='go()'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Add Branch</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a data-ui-sref="SavedDraft" data-ng-click='go()'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></i>   View Draft/Past Application</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;" data-ng-click="logOut()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>   Log Out </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>                               

                        </ul>
                    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

I got this error when I click on dropdown. I think it is because of jquery conflict. How to solve this?
        Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.u.error (jqueryTest?v=TAv6ydUG1iyOHUWGhs7LKsQ8xhfxrCjB3MDSXsgtZS41:1)
    at u.tokenize (jqueryTest?v=TAv6ydUG1iyOHUWGhs7LKsQ8xhfxrCjB3MDSXsgtZS41:1)
    at u.select (jqueryTest?v=TAv6ydUG1iyOHUWGhs7LKsQ8xhfxrCjB3MDSXsgtZS41:1)
    at Function.u [as find] (jqueryTest?v=TAv6ydUG1iyOHUWGhs7LKsQ8xhfxrCjB3MDSXsgtZS41:1)
    at i.fn.init.find (jqueryTest?v=TAv6ydUG1iyOHUWGhs7LKsQ8xhfxrCjB3MDSXsgtZS41:1)
    at new i.fn.init (jqueryTest?v=TAv6ydUG1iyOHUWGhs7LKsQ8xhfxrCjB3MDSXsgtZS41:1)
    at i (jqueryTest?v=TAv6ydUG1iyOHUWGhs7LKsQ8xhfxrCjB3MDSXsgtZS41:1)
    at u (bootstrap?v=a0JlrK3HWJYO4CANWtnjZQ6r-FHTgFewh3ItuNGmfr41:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement. (bootstrap?v=a0JlrK3HWJYO4CANWtnjZQ6r-FHTgFewh3ItuNGmfr41:1)
    at Function.each (jqueryTest?v=TAv6ydUG1iyOHUWGhs7LKsQ8xhfxrCjB3MDSXsgtZS41:1)

Comment: Can you create stackbitz or fiddle? so i can check your code in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use data-target="#myNavbar" on each of the li items to close it.

Comment: Should i put in li or <a> tag?

Comment: You should try your best to keep it a link (a with href).  Put a <li> and put the <a> inside the <li>.  The reason why so you can right click the link and open in new tab, etc.